# Stop end of scroll triggering another scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs in this sample code.  If you scroll down and past the end of the blue div, the overall body/div also scrolls down.  Is there a way to prevent the other scrolling effect even if I'm past a scroll boundary on the blue div?

```
i.e. when the blue div scrolls and reaches a boundary, nothing else should scroll.
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nXN9H/

css solution prefered, but a simple js/jquery solution would be suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```
body
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/nXN9H/1/)

You can also try this

```
<div onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';" onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto';" >
```

[JS Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/nXN9H/5/)

Comment: +1 for that onmouseover idea - that's going straight into my bag of tricks.